# Отправка post запроса и получение ответа

Tags: c#, post

Хочу сделать программу которая бы конвертировала ссылку(получение прямой ссылки), опишу алгоритм:

1. Пользователь в textbox вставляет такую ссылку `http://site.ru/download/тутданные/file-name.jpg.html/`.
2. Программа их этой ссылки берет фрагмент(тут данные), присваивает какой то переменной.
3. Отправляет post запрос на хост `http://site/download/getlink` с параметрами `sekret=тутданные, action=getlink_file, downloaded=1`
4. Получает ответ: переход по такому адресу

   `http://какой то сайт/api/web/getInstaller?transaction_id=79610604&token=b48aa6bae41a37394677dfe57d3f1a7a&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fs1.test.ru%2Fu%2Fcdaba1f3138e2e72a3a119b391c52aa4%2F67c00066b6%2FYKuRUX22rvI.jpg"`
5. Из этой ссылки мы берем только эту часть 
    `http%3A%2F%2Fs1.test.%2Fu%2Fcdaba1f3138e2e72a3a119b391c52aa4%2F67c00066b6%2FYKuRUX22rvI.jpg`
6. Открываем получившую ссылку открываем в браузере.

Как это реализовать? Если будите отправлять примеры, то комментируйте пожалуйста каждую строку, так у меня очень скудный

Comment: Эээ... А каким способом из `1` вы предполагаете получить `e4e8bf9199`?

Comment: В чем вообще состоит *вопрос*? @VladD я полагаю, имелась в виду переменная `string1`.

Comment: Пользователь вводит ссылку в поле, в переменной string 1 берется фрагмент из ссылки , после отправляется post запрос с 3 параметрами где первый параметр и есть string 1, после этого я хочу получить ответ, ответ это редирект на другую ссылку эту ссылку мне и надо получить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Адаптируя [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13061805/276994): вам нужно сказать

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "sekret", string1 },
        { "action", "getlink_file" },
        { "downloaded", "16" }
    };
    byte[] responsebytes = await client.UploadValuesTaskAsync("http://yourhost", reqparm);
    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
}
```

Вы получите ваш ответ в `response`. Дальше вытягивайте из него информацию в зависимости от её формата. `WebClient` проследует сам за редиректом, так что вам не нужно следить за Location.

Comment: Код в роде как не работает, точнее Студия сообщает об многих ошибках.

Comment: @edvardpotter: Какие именно ошибки? Вы все namespace'ы подключили?